# Find parametric equations for the tangent line to the curve with the given parametric equations at the speciﬁed point.

Tags: calculus, parametric

Find parametric equations for the tangent line to the curve
with the given parametric equations at the speciﬁed point.

<1+2$\sqrt{t}$ ,$t^{3}$-1 , $t^{3}$+1 > at point P(3,0,2)

Answer (score 1):

Call your curve $c$, then $t=1$ and the tangent line is achieved as usual:
$$s\mapsto c(t)+s\cdot \dot c(t)=(3,0,2)+s(1,3,3).
$$

Michael